# Display image with latitude and longitude position like augmented reality in Android

Tags: android, gps, augmented-reality

I have an array of position with latitude and longitude that are around the current user position, and i want display an image for every position of the array, if the user is looking in that direction Smart Glasses with Android (Moverio BT-200). I have made some research and I think I have to work with the Azimuth, in this way:

1. Get the GPS position of the user
2. Get the Azimuth
3. Define a distance view
4. Calculate the point inside that triangle to know what image of the array show to the user

This is more or less the summary, but I have another question, how can I let the user for example see only an half the image if he is looking in one position and the half image is in the edge of the screen?
Or how can I show the image behind the user when him for example turn back and during the movement let see him other image in the other position in the range of the distance view?